# how do I successfully use PDO with my ODBC for MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

- Windows Server 2016 64 bit (Fully Updated)
- WAMP/3.1.3 (Win32)
- Apache/2.4.33 (Win32)
- PHP/7.2.4 (Win32)

I am trying to connect to my database on a SQL Server but can't seem to get the connection working. I have tried several approaches, downloaded files, enabled extensions but none of them seem to work. I have established that the SQL Server has Named Pipes and that Remote Connections are allowed. I have also confirmed that he password and username work:

```
<?php

$driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}';
/* $driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'; */
/* $driver='{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}'; */
$dsn='phpodbc11';
$hostname='host01';
$database='data01';
$username='root';
$password='pass123';

$conn = new PDO("odbc:$dns")
$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username,$password);
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$database", $username, $password);
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;Server=$hostname;Database=$database", $username, $password);

?>
```

[image: Drivers Loaded on the Server]
[image: System DSNs loaded]

php.ini extensions :

- extension=pdo_odbc
- extension=php_mysqli.dll
- extension=php_ldap.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll

**Errors I get for each of the aforementioned new PDO attempts**

*SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

could not find driver

SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified*

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:
1.- Execute PDO Drivers/Version 3_2/SQLSRV32.exe
    Download from [PDO Drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098%20%20%20%20%20%20%20See%20compatibility%20table%20according%20your%20installed%20PHP%20version:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

```
First see compatibillity in [Drivers for PHP for SQL Server][2]
```

2.- Copy this DLLs in your WAMP directory

- php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

3.- Add this extension lines in your php.ini section Dynamic Extensions:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

4.- Restart apache WampServer
5.- Installl ODBC 11 in your machine:
    [ODBC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

```
Run: ODBC/msodbcsql.msi
```

6.- See phpinfo.php, now you must be this:

```
PDO  
PDO support enabled  
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, **sqlsrv**  

pdo_sqlsrv  
pdo_sqlsrv support  enabled  
Directive   Local Value Master Value  
pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size    10240   10240  
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity 0   0  

sqlsrv  
sqlsrv support  enabled  
Directive   Local Value Master Value  
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize    10240   10240  
sqlsrv.LogSeverity  0   0  
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems    0   0  
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors   On  On
```

Good luck